# How to get ip address from other host in ansible?

Tags: vagrant, ansible

I have vagrant configured with multiple machines and ansible:

```
config.vm.box = "ubuntu/trusty64"

config.vm.define "my_server" do |my_server|
    my_server.vm.network "private_network", ip: "192.168.50.4"
end

config.vm.define "my_agent" do |my_agent|
    my_agent.vm.network "private_network", ip: "192.168.50.5"
end

config.vm.provision "ansible" do |ansible|
    ansible.groups = {
        "my-server" => ["my_server"],
        "my-agent" => ["my_agent"],
        "all_groups:children" => ["my-server", "my-agent"]
    }
    ansible.playbook = "./ansible/my.yml"
end
```

And vagrant generate inventory file:

```
# Generated by Vagrant

my_server ansible_ssh_host=127.0.0.1 ansible_ssh_port=2222 ansible_ssh_private_key_file=/.../private_key
my_agent ansible_ssh_host=127.0.0.1 ansible_ssh_port=2200 ansible_ssh_private_key_file=/.../private_key
...
```

When I run vagrant `my_server` gets ip:

```
eth0: 10.0.2.15
eth1: 192.168.50.4
```

and `my_agent` gets ip:

```
eth0: 10.0.2.15
eth1: 192.168.50.5
```

I want to add in agent configuration ip address of server (from eth1).
I try debug informations about server:

```
- debug: var=hostvars[item]
  with_items: groups['my-server']
```

but i only gets:

```
ok: [my_agent] => (item=my_server) => {
    "item": "my_server", 
    "var": {
        "hostvars[item]": {
            "ansible_ssh_host": "127.0.0.1", 
            "ansible_ssh_port": 2222, 
            "ansible_ssh_private_key_file": ".../private_key", 
            "group_names": [
                "all_groups", 
                "my-server"
            ], 
            "inventory_hostname": "my_server", 
            "inventory_hostname_short": "my_server"
        }
    }
}
```

Is it possible to get ip address of server in agent role? If it is possible how I can do it?

Comment: Is there `gather_facts: no` in your playbook?

Comment: Can you use Ansible's built-in facts? 
Source: http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/playbooks_variables.html#information-discovered-from-systems-facts

Comment: I don't configure gather_facts. I try use hostvars. But I resolve problem. I need add ansible.limit = "all", because vagrant run separate process for each machine or group.

Answer (score 4):

I resolve problem. I need add

```
ansible.limit = "all"
```

in ansible configuration, because vagrant runs ansible two times: first for my_server and second for `my_agent`. Second run ansible don't collect informations about `my_server`. Now ansible runs two times for each server.

Working vagrant configuration:

```
config.vm.provision "ansible" do |ansible|
    ansible.groups = {
        "my-server" => ["my_server"],
        "my-agent" => ["my_agent"],
        "all_groups:children" => ["my-server", "my-agent"]
    }
    ansible.limit = "all"
    ansible.playbook = "./ansible/my.yml"
end
```

And ansible agent role:

```
- debug: var=hostvars[item]["ansible_eth1"]["ipv4"]["address"]
  with_items: groups['my-server']
  sudo: yes
```

Comment: This absolutely works! How come this is not documented in bold black letters in Ansible's docs?